# Setting a sibling div to take on the width of an audio control element

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div element and two nested div elements. The second child div is an audio control of arbitrary length. At least I assume it's arbitrary. My question is how can I get the first child div to take on the width of the audio control?

I want the title to appear on only one line and to be cut off if it exceeds the desired width.

I currently have max-width set to 100% which I know will not work because the parent div does not have a defined width. I do not want the parent div to expand beyond the width of the audio control.

```css
.outer: {
  border: solid black 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.audio_text: {
  background-color: #888;
  color: #f00;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
   <div class="audio_text">My Title</div>
   <div><audio src="audio.mp3" controls></audio></div>
</div>
```

How can I prevent the text from causing the parent div to increase in size?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this. The idea is to make the title `position:absolute` so it won't affect the parent width and you make it stretch the whole existing width defined by the audio tag. Then with some overflow properties you cut it when it's long.

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

/* To create the needed space for the title*/
.outer:before {
  content: "A";
  visibility: hidden;
}
/**/

.audio_text {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 0;
  left: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.audio_text: {
  background-color: #888;
  color: #f00;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="audio_text">My Title</div>
  <div><audio src="audio.mp3" controls></audio></div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="audio_text">very very looooooooooooooooooooooooong long Title</div>
  <div><audio src="audio.mp3" controls></audio></div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="audio_text">Another long Title</div>
  <div><audio src="audio.mp3" controls style="width:80px;"></audio></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The second child div is an audio control of arbitrary length. At least
>   I assume it's arbitrary.

`<audio>` is an inline element and the default width appears to be `300px` in Chrome, `270px` in Firefox,  and `250px` in Safari (I can't test IE / Edge at the moment).

With that information, you could give the container a fixed width of `300px`, and give the `audio` a `width: 100%`.

example...

```css
.outer {
  border: solid black 1px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

audio {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.audio_text {
  background-color: #888;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="audio_text">My Title My Title My Title My Title My Title My Title</div>
  <div><audio src="audio.mp3" controls></audio></div>
</div>
```